# How to add a jQuery element to another jQuery element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When you select a jQuery element, you usually get more than one, so is it possible to add them together if you select multiple jQuery elements?

For example:

```js
var foo = $("h1");
console.log(foo.length); //5
var foo2 = $("h2");
console.log(foo2.length); //2
foo1.addJQuery(foo2); //Is there are function like this?
console.log(foo1.length); //7 //supposed to log 7, because we added foo2
```

UPDATE:
People ask what my purpose is.

One example could be if i wanted to change the css color like this:

```js
var $foo1 = $("h1");
var $foo2 = $("h2");

$foo1.addJQuery($foo2);

//This should be equavelant to do this
var $foo3 = $("h1, h2"); 

$foo1.css("color", "red"); //Now all h1 and h2 elements will have the the css color red

//I would also be able to loop through all h1 and h2 elements as you would expect
for(var i = 0; i < $foo1.length; i++)
  console.log($foo1.eq(i).text());
```

I know this small example doesn't seem to be so useful (Because the example is made simple as possible), but i have a special case where i want to add them when i need to.

Comment: var $foo=$("h1"); will return the array of h1 element. in your DOM and h1 and h2 are different elements. so first explain more what you want to do.

Comment: if you want to merge two arrays `var $foo1 = $.merge($foo, $foo2);`

Comment: What is your use case and what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Question is lacking details. Please review [Question checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) and [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was found:

var $x = $.merge($foo1, $foo2);

Thank you devansh.

Comment: Even i was suggesting the same .. but, was unaware of `merge` :P

Answer (score 0):

You cannot merge like `foo1.addJQuery(foo2);`
But, as `$("h1");` selector is returning array of matched objects you..can store this in an `Array`..

and push the results of `$("h2");` into the same `array`.

So, now you have array containing the results of both `$("h1");` and `$("h2");` selectors.

You can now merge as many results as you want.